# Specifics access to a external docker registry with multi-users

Tags: image, docker, registry, docker-registry, rights

I've just created my first externally-accessible registry with Docker and set up the restricting access with one user and its password, my question is, is it possible to specify the rights? like a user access to a specific docker image of the registry and an other one only access to a different image?

Thanks by advance

Siva

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your own token server for this. Full spec is at: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/

One popular implementation is cesanra/docker_auth which can be found at:
https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth